# Navigating to a view other than the App's Launchscreen when App is closed

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on an App that has an implementation of the APNS. I have a tool that let's me simulate a Push-Notification, and it is working as intended. But this is only when the App is in the foreground or background.

When the App is in the foreground, and I receive a Push-Notification, I receive a UIAlert, with a button to press, with which I extract an ID in the payload to navigate to another ViewController.

When the App is in the background (not closed), and I receive a Push-Notification, I get a (depending on the device's settings) banner. When I click in the banner, the App comes into the foreground, and I receive the same UIAlert as mentioned above.

But when the App is closed entirely, and I receive a Push-Notification, I get the same banner as mentioned above, and the App opens up the same way, but then there's no UIAlert.

What I was wondering was, can I navigate to a UIViewController the same way as when the App is in the Foreground, when the App is closed? Is there a method that gets called when the App launches when a Push-Notification has been received?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The notification is in the options dictionary passed to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is no longer available in the C# AppDelegate. There is an options-Dictionary passed in the FinishedLaunching method of the AppDelegate, but there's no information on Push-Notifications in there.

Comment: I take that back. I was looking at the wrong variable. The NSDictionary options indeed contains the Push-Notification received. It is a bit of a hassle extracting the ID, but it works. Thanks Paul!